# Ansible apt module to execute with sudo

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get ansible to execute `sudo apt-get update`. I already have the `sudoers` setup to run without a password and it works if I login as the user ansible is using and execute `sudo apt-get update`. If I use the following ansible playbook

```
---
  - name: updates
    hosts: pis
    tasks:
      - name: Update APT
        become: true
        apt:
          update_cache: yes
```

It will give me the following error

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

but the following playbook works fine

```
---
  - name: updates
    hosts: pis
    tasks:
      - name: Update APT
        command: sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `become: yes` the connection will try to **spawn shell as root** (as you haven't specified `become_user`).

It seems you have access to run `sudo apt-get update` without password, i.e:

`/etc/sudodoers` may contain something similar to this:

`ansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/apt-get update`

To replicate the issue, login as user `ansible` and issue a command `sudo -i`

If you're using a dedicated user (`ansible` ?) for all ansible connectivity, you might want to give that user access to all commands via sudo without password. [Read Here](https://phpraxis.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/enable-sudo-without-password-in-ubuntudebian/) *this is however not the best practice, you are always better off giving access to specific commands for security reasons*

Add the following line to `/etc/sudoers` file using `visudo /etc/sudoers`

`ansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

If you opt for this, I would also advise to use a key-pair authentication for this privileged account rather than password authentication. [More info](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aews)

Comment: correct. I created the user ```ansible``` so that ansible can ssh via keys, and execute specific commands and specific sudo commands that are allowed in the ```/etc/sudoers``` ```sudo -l``` gave me this output which is slightly different from above you defined ```(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get update```. ```sudo -i``` output is ```Sorry, user ansible is not allowed to execute '/bin/zsh'``` do I need to added ```/bin/zsh``` to ```/etc/sudoers```?

Comment: The output of `sudo -i` indicates that user `ansible` cannot start shell as root, which is exactly what you're experiencing with ansible when trying to `become: yes` (or `become: true`). If you think about it, giving `ansible` access to run a full shell as root, you will allow that user run any commands as root within it, including spawning other shells. Therefore, it would probably be more reasonable to add the following line to `sudoers` file `ansible ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL` as per the article I linked above. `ALL=(ALL)`  simply means user can execute commands as ANY user.

Comment: that sense now. Thank you.